# Perl like anonymous subroutines in ruby

Tags: ruby, perl

I'm new to ruby and trying to duplicate this perl, that calls anonymous subroutines, in ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# Make a reference to a subroutine
my $codes = {
   one => sub {
      say "This is code block one";
      say "And this is code block one's line two"
   },
};

for my $next_code ( keys %{ $codes } ) {
   # Execute anonymous subroutine
   &{ $codes->{ $next_code } };
}
```

I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

codes = {
   one: puts "This is code block one"
        puts "And this is code block one's line two",
 }
codes.each do |next_code|
   next_code
end
```

But, I get syntax errors. Is this possible, or is there another preferred ruby way?

UPDATE: Yes, this is like a dispatch table. I store code in a hash and run that code later.

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to implement a dispatch table. If so, it would be good to mention that in your question to avoid the XY problem. There might be a better way to do it in Ruby that takes a completely different approach than Perl.

Comment: Can you explain in common words(not perl code) what do you want to do?

Comment: `&{ $codes->{ $next_code } }` is best written `$codes->{ $next_code }->()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby has [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html)s as anonymous first-class subroutine objects. `Proc`s can be created by passing a block to [`Proc::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-c-new), [`Kernel#proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-proc), or [`Kernel#lambda`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda), or with the "stabby lambda" lambda literal syntax.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Make a reference to a subroutine
codes = {
  one: -> {
    puts "This is code block one"
    puts "And this is code block one's line two"
  }
}

codes.each do |name, code|
  # Execute anonymous subroutine
  code.()
end
```

The most widely-used form of anonymous code block in Ruby is a construct called a *block*, which is actually *not* an object, but just a syntactic construct. Every method in Ruby takes exactly one optional block argument, which can be passed either in curly braces or using a `do`/`end` keyword pair after the normal method arguments. You can see a block in action in the code above, being passed to the [`Hash#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-each) iteration method.

In case you are interested, here is a small toy project of mine that demonstrates the use of first-class closures in a variety of languages, including Perl5 and Perl6, Ruby, PHP, Python, ECMAScript, Smalltalk, Clojure, Scheme, and many others: http://joergwmittag.github.io/lambdaconscarcdr/

Comment: One thing interesting about procs is that they can be called in (at least?) five ways. Suppose `f = ->s { puts "Say #{s}!" }`. Then `f.call('hey')`, `f['hey']`, `f.('hey')`, `f.yield('hey')` and `f === "hey"` all print `"Say hey!"`.

Comment: Although the "normal" way is to use `call` or its syntactic sugar `.()`. `[]` is an outdated alias for `call` that was used to make calling a `Proc` more like a method call by using the brackets as fake parentheses. As of Ruby 1.9, we have the `.()` notation, which serves this purpose better, IMO. `yield` I didn't know about, I suppose it is for API compatibility with `Fibre`s? `===` is useful for using `Proc`s in `case` expressions and `Enumerable#grep`, but probably shouldn't be called directly. Note: all of them are aliases for `call`, except `()`, which is syntax sugar for `call`.